# Is it possible to import conent of Manifext.XML file to MonkeyRunner script file

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am writing MonkeyRunner script which checks state of wifi and enables it.

For doing so I am importing android API and its classes. Below is code snippet;

```
from android.net.wifi import WifiManager
global state
state = WifiManager.isWifiEnabled()
print state
```

While executing I am getting an error as:

```
state = WifiManager.isWifiEnabled()
TypeError: isWifiEnabled(): expected 1 args; got 0
```

Then I realized I need permission for doing wifi operation and found in some Manifest.XML file, where they have used

My doubt is I am running the script on real device and how can I use 
  in my MonkeyRunner script file.

Thanks in Advance
Surendra Valsangker

Comment: It's not clear from where you are importing your classes...

Comment: from android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-17 platform folder I have imported android.jar and kept it in android-sdk-windows\tools folder where monkeyrunner.bat and my script file is present. as I informed in my script file I have used "from android.net.wifi import WifiManager" to access WifiManager class